# visual studio 2022 でプロジェクトに追加したファイルが「保留中の追加」のまま

Tags: visual-studio

visual studio 2022 でプロジェクトのソースファイルに新たにファイルを追加したところ、
ファイル名の左側のアイコンが緑の＋で「保留中の追加」になっており、ビルドの際に認識されていません。

このファイルをプロジェクトのファイルとして認識させるには、どのような操作が必要でしょうか？

Comment: Bing Copilotに「Visual Studio 2022 C# 緑色の+アイコン 保留中の追加 とは何？」で聞いたら **「保留中の追加」とは、ファイルや変更がローカルリポジトリに追加され、まだコミットされていない状態を指します。つまり、これらの変更はまだバージョン管理システムに永続的に記録されていないということです。** との答えでした。アイコンと「プロジェクトのファイルとして認識」させるのは別かもしれませんね。この辺の記事が何か参考になるかも。[コードの開発と保留中の変更の管理](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/develop-code-manage-pending-changes?view=azure-devops), [ソリューション エクスプローラーについて学習する](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/ide/use-solution-explorer?view=vs-2022)

Answer (score 0):

> visual studio 2022 でプロジェクトのソースファイルに新たにファイルを追加したところ、
> ファイル名の左側のアイコンが緑の＋で「保留中の追加」になっており

「左側のアイコンが緑の＋で・・・」というのが分からないので違う話かもしれませんが・・・

例えば Windows のエクスプローラーで他のプロジェクトの .cs ファイルをコピーしたとすると、それを Visual Studio のソリューションエクスプローラーで見ると以下のようになります。そのファイルを右クリックして［プロジェクトに含める(j)」ということで目的は果たせませんか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

**【追記】**

> GitHubにファイルをコミットすることで解決しました。

とのことですが、どのような環境になっているのでしょうか、教えていただけませんか？

「ファイル名の左側のアイコンが緑の＋」というのが Visual Studio にバージョン管理システムを導入した結果のようでしたので、自分の環境 (Visual Studio 2022 17.8.3) で以下の記事のようにして試してみました。

GitHub リポジトリを作成する
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/version-control/git-create-repository?view=vs-2022#create-a-github-repo

そして、例えば、ソリューションエクスプローラーを操作して Class.cs というクラスファイル新規作成すると、下の画像の赤枠で示したようにファイル名の左に「緑の＋」が表示されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

その後、そのクラスファイルを使ったコードを既存のファイルに追加して (上の画像の青枠のファイル) ソリューションをビルドすれば、ビルド結果には追加・変更が反映されます。

> 「保留中の追加」になっており、ビルドの際に認識されていません。

ということはなかったので、上の記事「GitHub リポジトリを作成する」以上のことを設定した環境のようですが・・・

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ご提示いただいた表示は出ませんでしたが、GitHubにファイルをコミットすることで解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: どのような環境になっているのでしょうか？　Git を利用したバージョン管理システムを導入しているとか？